# Getting ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS error in a trigger with a query to a linked server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm using SMSS (MS SQL Server 2008R2) and I've created this apparently simple trigger in a table from a database in server X to insert data to a table in a database in server Y. The creation of the trigger works fine, but when I run the application that actually fires that trigger, I get the error: "Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection. This ensures consistent query semantics. Enable these options and then reissue your query linked server."

Here's the trigger:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
set ansi_warnings on
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.InsertData 
   ON  dbo.BaseTable 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    Insert into TargetTable(Name)

    SELECT     BaseName
    FROM       Inserted INNER JOIN
                      [SERVER Y].targetDB.dbo.Table1 AS Table1 ON Inserted.Name = Table1.Name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS

END
GO
```

Is this a problem specific to the application that's interacting with the database?

Thanks

Comment: This is because you are doing a query against a remote server that is not sql server. It requires that ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS be set to ON. A quick google search of your error message would likely reveal the same thing.

Comment: But the remote server is in fact SQL Server, only a different version. May this be the cause for the error? Base server is 10.50.4042 and remote server is 9.0.5000...I've already set ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS to ON on both servers but it didn't solve the problem...

Comment: In general, don't do this. Triggers should be fast and light, and the fact that a remote server is currently unreachable shouldn't generally be a reason to tie up the transaction for 30 seconds before timing out and forcing a rollback of the original change. If possible, switch to a plan where the trigger records the need for a change locally (in a table, or a service broker queue) and something else (decoupled from the original insert) then completes the external data access as and when it is possible to do so.

Comment: Should I be implementing ETL for this?